# Hello i'm trying to do multiple sorting using php mysql where i'm searching and then sorting the data

Tags: php, mysqli, tablesorter

i'm printing a table in php where data is coming from mysql now i'm creating functionalities like searching and sorting so  when i click on sort it sorts the data and when i click on search i get searched data now the problem is i want to perform sorting on searched data like for example i sorted the data and then i searched for words starting with a i.e i got results like adam,azan,anand so i want to perform resorting on these searched data and get data as adam,anand,azan
my approach is:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['search_btn'])){
  $search=$_GET['search'];
  $result=GetWords(mysqli_escape_string($conn,$search));
}
/*if(isset($_GET['q'])){
      $id=$_GET['q'];
      $result=GetWordsById($id);
    }*/
    if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
      $sort=$_GET['sort'];
    }
    if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
      if($sort=="asc"){
        $result=SortContent();//Here Get Sort Content is a function calling Store Procedure SortContent which is working at first sorting
      }
      if($sort=="desc"){
        $result=SortContent2();
      }
    }


    else{
  $result=GetAdminWords();
}
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
  ?>  
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <th>Word</th>
        <th>Meaning</th>
        <th>Synonym</th>
        <th>Antonym</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
      <tbody>
        <tr>

          <td><a href="view.php?q=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['word'];?></a></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['meaning'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['synonym'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['antonym'];?></td>
         <td><a href="admin.php?id1=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a> <a onClick="javascript: return confirm('Please confirm deletion');" href="view.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a> </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <?php
  }?>
```

and i'm talking in context of large amount of data i hope i have made myself clear and if possible how can i implement ajax using mysqli

Answer (score 1):

You will need to trigger an event in JavaScript, which in turn will use your HTML search input, which is then sent to the server, where a query will be executed and the results returned (as HTML) to the JavaScript code, and finally placed back on the page. At least this is how I solve my ajax searches...

So the flow could be something like:

Input -> JavaScript event -> ajax -> result -> page

Here is some code that might get you started, though I haven't tested i myself:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="my_search_input">
<div id="my_search_result"></div>
```

JS (jQuery):

```
var $inputField = $( "#my_search_input" ); 
var $result = $( "#my_search_result" );
$inputField.on('keyup', function(){ //triggered when a pressed key is lifted
    var searchTerm = $inputField.val();
    $.ajax({
         url:"/mySearch.php",
         method:"post",
         data:{searchTerm:searchTerm},
         success:function(response){ //response contains the data from mySearch.php
             var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
             var resultHtml = parsedResponse.html; //this is the array key of what the PHP script returns
             $result.append(resultHtml);
         }
    });
});
```

PHP

```
$searchTerm = $_POST['searchTerm']; //$_POST['searchTerm'] is what we defined in data:{... in the ajax call
// here is where you need to retrieve data from your database
// the db result needs to be processed into HTML and assigned to a variable
$html = "<div>My result based on data</div>";
return json_encode(['html' => $html]);
```

Comment: Hello @Kyrre  i wanted to sort data using php if you see i have done sorting which sorts the data at first and then i search for the data and then i want to perform sorting again on searched data using php only i appreciate your help....